# Strange exception occurring on IE7 and not on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is the trace of the error from the system log:

> Event Type:   Error
>
> Event Source: .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
>
> Event Category:   None
>
> Event ID: 5000
>
> Date:     17/07/2011
>
> Time:     13:11:56
>
> User:     N/A
>
> Computer: WORKSTATION
>
> Description:
>
> EventType clr20r3, P1 iexplore.exe, P2 7.0.6000.17055, P3 4bc5e60e, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4a7cd8f7, P7 35f9, P8 444, P9 exception, P10 NIL.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>
> Data:
>
> 0000: 63 00 6c 00 72 00 32 00   c.l.r.2.
>
> 0008: 30 00 72 00 33 00 2c 00   0.r.3.,.
>
> 0010: 20 00 69 00 65 00 78 00    .i.e.x.
>
> 0018: 70 00 6c 00 6f 00 72 00   p.l.o.r.
>
> 0020: 65 00 2e 00 65 00 78 00   e...e.x.
>
> 0028: 65 00 2c 00 20 00 37 00   e.,. .7.
>
> 0030: 2e 00 30 00 2e 00 36 00   ..0...6.
>
> 0038: 30 00 30 00 30 00 2e 00   0.0.0...
>
> 0040: 31 00 37 00 30 00 35 00   1.7.0.5.
>
> 0048: 35 00 2c 00 20 00 34 00   5.,. .4.
>
> 0050: 62 00 63 00 35 00 65 00   b.c.5.e.
>
> 0058: 36 00 30 00 65 00 2c 00   6.0.e.,.
>
> 0060: 20 00 6d 00 73 00 63 00    .m.s.c.
>
> 0068: 6f 00 72 00 6c 00 69 00   o.r.l.i.
>
> 0070: 62 00 2c 00 20 00 32 00   b.,. .2.
>
> 0078: 2e 00 30 00 2e 00 30 00   ..0...0.
>
> 0080: 2e 00 30 00 2c 00 20 00   ..0.,. .
>
> 0088: 34 00 61 00 37 00 63 00   4.a.7.c.
>
> 0090: 64 00 38 00 66 00 37 00   d.8.f.7.
>
> 0098: 2c 00 20 00 33 00 35 00   ,. .3.5.
>
> 00a0: 66 00 39 00 2c 00 20 00   f.9.,. .
>
> 00a8: 34 00 34 00 34 00 2c 00   4.4.4.,.
>
> 00b0: 20 00 65 00 78 00 63 00    .e.x.c.
>
> 00b8: 65 00 70 00 74 00 69 00   e.p.t.i.
>
> 00c0: 6f 00 6e 00 20 00 4e 00   o.n. .N.
>
> 00c8: 49 00 4c 00 0d 00 0a 00   I.L.....

Comment: Without sample code, this question isn't ready to answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is not a difference between IE7 and IE8.

The difference is that the requests are coming from different machines.

On the machine where it works the site is a trusted site. On the machine where it does not work the site is in the internet zone.

Comment: It aint that, added the site address to trusted sites and it still crushes

Comment: did you restart IE after you added it to the trusted site, sometimes it helps due to problems on current page